# jQuery Deferreds and Managing the Order of Code Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.5, jquery-deferred

I have been trying to understand the benefits of jQuery's Deferred functionality. If I understand correctly Deferred's **doesn't** offer an alternative to callbacks but rather offers better management of callbacks? If I am writing a method and I want to be sure that it has finished executing before running another task I would still need a callback to set the `deferred.resolve`? Here is a code example to illustrate what I think is correct:

This is the parent function. I want to ensure '*AddItemsToList*' has completed before I select the default. (This isn't a real function, just an example).

```
function PopulateListAndSelectDefault(list,default)
{
   var resultObject = AddItemsToList($('#myList'), list);

   successObject.Success(function(){
      SelectItemInList($('#myList'), default);
   });
}
```

This would be the **incorrect** way to write the '*AddItemsToList*' function:

```
function AddItemsToList (jquerySelectList,items)
{
   var result= $.Deferred();
   $.each(items, function (i, _property) 
   {
      if (CheckElementIsSelectList(_property.Value)) 
      {
          jQueryListItem.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", _property.value).text(_property.DisplayText)); //Add Item
      }
   }
   result.resolve;
   return result;      
}
```

Instead, the **correct** way, would be to continue to use a callback but this time only resolve the deferred object so that I can attach futher success/failure methods later down the line if I so wished?

Have I understood correctly? What would be the correct way to write the code above or have I completely misunderstood the fundamentals? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is most useful for asynchronous functions. This is a utility class for managing callbacks.

> jQuery.Deferred() is a chainable utility object that can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.

> jQuery.Deferred() provides flexible ways to provide multiple callbacks, and these callbacks can be invoked regardless of whether the original callback dispatch has already occurred.

The correct use of [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), in an asynchronous function, is to return a [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), and [`resolve`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) the Deferred once the asynchronous operation has been done.

Pass any value (maybe the result of the function) to .resolve() and the registered callbacks will receive that value.

Example:

```
function getSomething() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred;
    $.get('/get-something', function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

myAsynchronousFunction().done(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

In this case this is equivalent to:

```
function getSomething(callback) {
    $.get('/get-something', function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}

myAsynchronousFunction(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```